# How to get React frontend and Django backend to run on HTTPS? ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, https, vps

My web application is running on a Linux Ubuntu 20.04.4 VPS server and its IP is assigned to a domain name.

- React frontend has an SSL certificate and is running on port 443.
- API (written in Django) is running inside a Docker container on port
  1414 with no SSL.

Frontend's attempts to send requests to the API result in ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR getting thrown in the console. How can I get my backend to run on HTTPS? Do I need to create another certificate within my Docker container, or do I have to configure something in the domain?
For now, my colleague wrote a script in PHP that somehow manages to bypass the error and make the requests. However, this seems like a very insecure way of doing things and is only a temporary solution.

Below you'll find my Nginx configuration files

```
# etc/nginx/sites-available/default

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
    root /var/www/html;
    
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm  index.nginx-debian.html;
    
    server_name _;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
    
}


server {
    
    root /var/www/html;
    
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm  index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name www.domainname.com domainname.com; # managed by Certbot
    
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
    
    rewrite ^/api/get/(.*)$ /api.php?method=get&url=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/api/post/(.*)$ /api.php?method=post&url=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/api/put/(.*)$ /api.php?method=put&url=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/api/delete/(.*)$ /api.php?method=delete&url=$1 last;
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
    
    
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    server_name img.domainname.com;
    
    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1414/static/media/uploads/meal/;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        
        proxy_set_header Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    }
    
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/img.domainname.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/img.domainname.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
}

server {
    if ($host = www.domainname.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
    
    if ($host = domainname.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
    
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name www.domainname.com domainname.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}


server {
    if ($host = img.domainname.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
    
    listen 80;
    server_name img.domainname.com;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

```
# /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}


http {
        # Basic Settings
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;


        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POOD                                                                                                             LE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

And this is my Nginx config file inside my Docker container (for the backend)

```
server {
    listen ${LISTEN_PORT};

    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass              ${APP_HOST}:${APP_PORT};
        include                 /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        client_max_body_size    10M;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you'd post your current nginx configuration first?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Good point. I edited my question.